# the read only property is not able to disable using jquery

Tags: jquery

In the jquery

According to some condition I make one field as read only with below code

```
$("#name").attr("readonly", true);
```

it is working fine

but when i try to disable it by using below codes

```
$("#name").attr("readonly", false);
           OR
$("#name").attr("disabled", false);
```

It is not getting disabled. How can achieve it

Comment: $("#name").attr("readonly", ""); removes the attribute.

Comment: _but when i try to disable it_ != `disabled = false` O.o, also you should be using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`

Comment: Check these two jsfiddles: [jsfiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/3mG8g/1/), [jsfiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/6jFMf/20/) ... `disabled` should have `disabled` or `null` for the `$...attr()`

Comment: I closed this a duplicate. The other question is about `disabled`, not `readonly`, but it should be the same.

Comment: thanks all of u for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the disabled attribute does not matter. If it is in the attribute list, the element will be disabled regardless of whether it is `false` or `true` or *empty*. You need to remove the attribute to enable it back.

Use `$("#name").removeAttr('disabled')` is re-enable the element.